# how to read CSS pseudo selector class value with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

How can I get the CSS pseudo selector class value (`:checked`) using JavaScript? Below is my CSS class description which is defined for `::after`.

```
.mbx-checkbox[_ngcontent-yhp-10] .check[_ngcontent-yhp-10] input[type="checkbox"][_ngcontent-yhp-10]:checked + label[_ngcontent-yhp-10]::after
```

All I want is to read the (`:checked`) value from the above definition and not to get any style values.

Comment: You mean you need to read the CSS file and retrieve a list of all selectors that have a `:checked` pseudo-class, a list of all inputs on the page that respond to selectors like that, a list of all such inputs that are currently checked, or what?

Comment: Your problem are with js or css? Where is your js code?